# SignalR: Can't get external Hub access according to official documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

In my MVC 5 application I want to get external access to my Hub methods.
I did it just like they say in the [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub)

My version:

```
public class GameModel
{
    ApplicationDbContext db;
    GameRoom gameroom;

    public GameModel(ApplicationDbContext context, GameRoom room)
    {
        this.db = context;
        this.gameroom = room;
    }

    //Allows GameRoomHub method calls 
    private readonly static Lazy<GameModel> _instance = new Lazy<GameModel>(
    () => new GameModel(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GameRoomHub>()));

    private IHubContext hubcontext;

    private GameModel(IHubContext context)
    {
        hubcontext = context;
    }
```

But in my case, the private constructor at the bottom is never called, and so "hubcontext" is always null when I try to do something with it.

I get the feeling that didn't understand an essential part of that example code snippet.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's probably because of the more detailed *public* constructor. Try removing it. The private constructor is private so the hub *can't* be instantiated by anyone except the SignalR framework. Dependency injection containers typically pick the most-detailed constructor to inject, which here is the public one. The public constructor both defeats the purpose of having a private one and prevents injection of the hub context

Comment: I tried to give the second constructor several dummy parameters (so that it has more than the first constructor) and tried to make it public, too. None of that worked... even if I changed everything in my example to public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wont work, what you can do is this

```
 public GameModel(ApplicationDbContext context, GameRoom room) : this(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GameRoomHub>())
    {
        this.db = context;
        this.gameroom = room;
    }
```

However having direct dependency on SignalR is bad practice, plus GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext is a service locator pattern which also is a anti pattern.

Readup on how to use a IoC with SignalR for example Ninject, then you can do this.

```
public class SignalRAbstraction : IAbstraction 
{

    public SignalRAbstraction(IConnectionManager connectionManager) 
    {
       var hubContext = connectionManager.GetHubContext<GameRoomHub>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. But why is this in the official documentation if it's bad practice? I thought this Lazy<T> thing was nice for performance.

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/DefaultDependencyResolver.cs#L54 Config.manager is a singleton so I cant see any performance gain. Also, examples like that seldom display good practice, it just focus on showing the functionality. SignalR everywhere is no better than Sql everywhere

Comment: I meant the lazy initialization by performance gain. And I still don't understand why the example works in the official documentation, but not in my example.

Comment: How are you consuming _instance ?

Comment: Like I said... They didn't have to use it in the example, so I thought that piece of code works. Can you tell me how I'd consume _instance the right way? Do I have to explicitely call it?

Comment: yepp. _instance.Value will consume it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I can use the hubcontext via `_instance.Value.hubcontext`. Perfect! But that means the official example in fact can not work o_o

Comment: They state "This sample only shows code related to getting and using the SignalR context." Anyway, please refactor so that you do not have such direct dependency to the HubContext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74789/discussion-between-tornister-and-anders).